# How to get native socket file describer from boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>?

Tags: c++, linux, boost, boost-asio

I am using `boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>`, but I need to run

```
setsockopt(mSocket.native_handle(), SOL_TCP, TCP_USER_TIMEOUT, &tcpTimeout, sizeof(int));
```

I've got a compile error:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >::native_handle_type {aka ssl_st*}’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
```

How to get native socket file descriptor for `boost::asio` socket?

Thank you.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

[`ssl::stream::native_handle()`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__stream/native_handle.html) returns the SSL stream handle (in case of OpenSSL of type `SSL*`).

To get the handle to the underlying socket, use [`ssl::stream::lowest_layer()`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__stream/lowest_layer.html):

```
setsockopt( sslStream.lowest_layer().native_handle(), ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this at all. Its slightly more cumbersome but you should instead define a  [socket option](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/SettableSocketOption.html) all you have to do is define one that can take a protocol and returns the options you have listed there here is an example for SOL_TCP.

```
class TCPUserTimeout{
template<typename Protocol>
int name(Protocol p){ return TCP_USER_TIMEOUT;}
// And so on...
};
```

You could even construct something general using structs that's quick and dirty for all options.If you do that I recommend using `unique_ptr` for storing the `option_value`